# How to print with itertools groupby?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have this code:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]

group = groupby(text)

for k, g in group:
    print(k, end= " ")
    print(sum(1 for _ in g), end=" ")
```

Example what I need:

```
A B C
2 2 1
```

My `itertools` only shows like this:

```
A 2 B 2 C 1
```

Comment: The way you're using print you can't do that in one for loop. Why not use two for loops?

Comment: how can I use two for loops? can you help me?

Comment: be aware: groupby luckly works well because the identical values follow each other, if they were mixed, you'd end up with multiple groups for the same value, UNLESS you first sort the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this which post-processes the results `groupby` returns to make it easy to get the values needed for each row of the output:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]

groups = [(k, str(sum(1 for _ in g))) for k, g in groupby(text)]
a, b = zip(*groups)
print(' '.join(a))  # -> a b c
print(' '.join(b))  # -> 2 2 1
```

Comment: `zip(*groups)` looks beautiful.

Comment: @j1-lee: Indeed, many folks are unaware that `zip()` can also unzip.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple print statements with [transpose](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-transpose-a-matrix-in-python)

```
from itertools import groupby

text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]

group = groupby(text)

# Transpose so we have row 0 with group names, and row 1 with grouping items
transposed = [(k, list(g)) for k, g in group]

for k in transposed:
    print(k[0], end = " ")
print()
for k in transposed:
    print(sum(1 for _ in k[1]), end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more alternative:

```
from itertools import groupby

text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]

group = groupby(text)
dictionary = {}

for k, g in group:
    dictionary[k] = sum(1 for _ in g)

keys = " ".join(list(dictionary.keys()))
values = " ".join(str(v) for v in list(dictionary.values()))

print(keys)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked about itertools.groupby, BUT I would use a Counter for such task:

```
>>> text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(text)
>>> print(c)
Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
>>> headers = c.keys()
>>> values = [str(val) for val in c.values()]
>>> print(' '.join(headers))
a b c
>>> print(' '.join(values))
2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `groupby()` does not lend itself to deploying `tee()` to make a copy,
the best solution seems to be to create a tuple comprehension. Note that
we're not interested in the values contained in each group g, so we'll just
store the length of the tuple constructed on the fly from the group.

```
import itertools

text = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]

group = tuple((k,len(tuple(v))) for k,v in itertools.groupby(text))

for t in group:
    print(t[0], end= " ")
print()
for t in group:
    print(t[1], end=" ")
print()
# a b c
# 2 2 1
```